# While treating 4-aminophenol with acetic anhydride why does the reaction stop at Paracetamol and does not undergo esterification with acetic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, amines, esters

This needs a little background so I will be showing you a question from one of my Organic Chemistry problem books:-
[image]

Now, the book shows the answer as Option (c)  which is Paracetamol.
I tried to work out the mechanism and I was pondering over the fact that the
products left in the reaction are Paracetamol and Ethanoic acid . Now Paracetamol contains an **-OH(Hydroxy group)** and **O**(Oxygen) atom can easily aquire positive charge by **mesomeric stabilisation** and attack **Ethanoic acid** to further form ester **(as in Option (a))** . Can someone please help me out ?

Comment: Acetates of phenol are pretty as good acylating agents and don't survive aqueous base work up

Comment: There is no stoichiometry in your reaction. If Ac2O is in excess, then A is the answer and Waylander's comment applies to form C. If the stoichiometry is 1:1, then C>>B. Heating this mixture, possibly neat, would convert B into C. Can you figure out why?

Comment: There are other underlying issues with your description. Firstly, what do you mean by oxygen "acquiring a positive charge", and secondly, why should that be of any help with esterification? If your oxygen is acting as a nucleophile, you probably *don't* want it to be positively charged.